# How to save loaded model in localstorage or IndexedDB

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I'm useing [TFJS's samle program](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-models/tree/master/coco-ssd). I'd like to save loaded model in localstorage or IndexedDB. So I wrote this program.

```
<!-- Load TensorFlow.js. This is required to use coco-ssd model. -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs"> </script>
<!-- Load the coco-ssd model. -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow-models/coco-ssd"> </script>

<!-- Replace this with your image. Make sure CORS settings allow reading the image! -->
<img id="img" src="cat.jpg"/>

<!-- Place your code in the script tag below. You can also use an external .js file -->
<script>
  // Notice there is no 'import' statement. 'cocoSsd' and 'tf' is
  // available on the index-page because of the script tag above.

  const img = document.getElementById('img');

  // Load the model.
  cocoSsd.load().then(model => {

    // save to localstorage. <-- My code
    model.save('localstorage://test') 

    // detect objects in the image.
    model.detect(img).then(predictions => {
      console.log('Predictions: ', predictions);
    });
  });
</script>
```

However `model.save('localstorage://test')`  got error that is `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: model.save is not a function`.

How to save model in localstorage or IndexedDB?

Answer (score 0):

Let's check whether you really can save the model by checking the methods that exist on it.

```js
function getMethods(o) {
  return Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Object.getPrototypeOf(o))
    .filter(m => 'function' === typeof o[m])
}

cocoSsd.load().then(model => {
  console.log(getMethods(model));
})
```

Output:

```js
["constructor","getPrefix","load","infer","buildDetectedObjects","calculateMaxScores","detect","dispose"]
```

Looking at the methods, the error is in fact correct, that the method `save` does not exist on a `cocoSsd` model. So you cannot directly save the model to the local storage or to a database.

No worries, you can just download the original model from a list of all the available object detection models which can be found [TensorFlow 2 Detection Model Zoo](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/tf2_detection_zoo.md). All of them are trained on the same coco dataset so you can choose any of them.

For example I chose [centernet_mobilenetv2_fpn_od](http://download.tensorflow.org/models/object_detection/tf2/20210210/centernet_mobilenetv2fpn_512x512_coco17_od.tar.gz).

Downloading the file and unzipping it will produce the following:

```bash
|-- checkpoint
|   |-- checkpoint
|   |-- ckpt-301.data-00000-of-00001
|   `-- ckpt-301.index
|-- label_map.txt
|-- model.tflite
|-- pipeline.config
`-- saved_model
    |-- assets
    |-- saved_model.pb
    `-- variables
        |-- variables.data-00000-of-00001
        `-- variables.index
```

What you want is `saved_model.pb` which you need to convert to a format that is usable by Tensorflow.js. To do this you can use the `tensorflowjs_wizard` which you run in the terminal:

```bash
>> tensorflowjs_wizard                                                     
Welcome to TensorFlow.js Converter.
? Please provide the path of model file or the directory that contains model files. 
If you are converting TFHub module please provide the URL.  .
? What is your input model format? (auto-detected format is marked with *)  Tensorflow Saved Model *
? What is tags for the saved model?  serve
? What is signature name of the model?  signature name: serving_default
? Do you want to compress the model? (this will decrease the model precision.)  No compression (Higher accuracy)
? Please enter shard size (in bytes) of the weight files?  4194304
? Do you want to skip op validation? 
This will allow conversion of unsupported ops, 
you can implement them as custom ops in tfjs-converter.  No
? Do you want to strip debug ops? 
This will improve model execution performance.  Yes
? Do you want to enable Control Flow V2 ops? 
This will improve branch and loop execution performance.  Yes
? Do you want to provide metadata? 
Provide your own metadata in the form: 
metadata_key:path/metadata.json 
Separate multiple metadata by comma.  
? Which directory do you want to save the converted model in?  /Users/yravindranath/Downloads/centernet_mobilenetv2_fpn_od/saved_model/model
converter command generated:
tensorflowjs_converter --control_flow_v2=True --input_format=tf_saved_model --metadata= --saved_model_tags=serve --signature_name=serving_default --strip_debug_ops=True --weight_shard_size_bytes=4194304 . /Users/yravindranath/Downloads/centernet_mobilenetv2_fpn_od/saved_model/model
```

This will produce the following in the specified save path:

```bash
./
|-- group1-shard1of3.bin
|-- group1-shard2of3.bin
|-- group1-shard3of3.bin
`-- model.json
```

Then you can load the model in your Javascript application using this function if you want to load it directly from local storage:

```js
const tf = require('@tensorflow/tfjs');
const tfnode = require('@tensorflow/tfjs-node');

async function loadModel(){

    const model = await loadGraphModel("path to model.json");
    // You can even save it to a github repo and load it in using a GET request like so:
    // const model = await loadGraphModel("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hugozanini/TFJS-object-detection/master/models/web_model/model.json");
    console.log("Model loaded")
}

loadModel();
```

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I created tensorflow.js model by `tensorflowjs_wiserd`. Then I loaded the model by loadModel(). getMethods() returns deferent with cocoSsd.loaded model's methods. Should I back to `tensorflowjs_wiserd`, does not I?